# Pandas: Selecting rows from a Dataframe using a Series of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a list of surnames in a Series, s:

```
print(s)

Order
1       Surname01
2       Surname02
3       Surname03
4       Surname04
5       Surname05
          ...    
496     Surname06
497     Surname07
498     Surname08
499     Surname09
500     Surname10
```

I have tabulated names, addresses, phone numbers, etc. in a Dataframe, df:

```
           Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1  ...           Phone      Unnamed: 7
Last Name                            ...                                
Surname01           0           NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
Surname02           1           NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
Surname11           2           NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
Surname12           3           NaN  ...  (123) 456-7890  (123) 456-7890
Surname05           4           NaN  ...  (123) 456-7890  (123) 456-7890
...               ...           ...  ...             ...             ...
Surname13          94           NaN  ...  (123) 456-7890  (123) 456-7890
Surname14          95           NaN  ...  (123) 456-7890  (123) 456-7890
Surname15          96           NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
Surname16          97           NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
Surname17          98           NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
```

I want to create a new table from df with only the surnames in s.
I've read many pages but cannot figure this out. This is where I'm at:

```
df = df.loc[s]
```

But I get KeyError: 'Last Name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `df.loc[df.index.isin(s), :]`

Example

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'f', 'd'], 
                  data={'col1': [10, 11, 12], 'col2': [1, 2, 3]})

df.loc[df.index.isin(s), :]

   col1  col2
a    10     1
d    12     3
```

Comment: You made that look easy.